# MAAS Users and LDAP integration

Tags: maas, ldap

I have 20+ users on my staff (which is constantly fluctuating) and it is a little inconvenient to constantly add/delete accounts in multiple places. Will MAAS eventually support LDAP so I only have to update one location? Thanks for your help!